# Adjusting the unusual format in a DataFrame, function continues to return None

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe and am runnning this function to adjust the format of the time. Time is formatted in unique ways with some garbage values.

I have tried different return statements, assigning different values to understand how it works and went through all the documentation but still can't figure out why this function keeps returning None.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({violation_time: ['+.98P','1037A', '0231P', '1206A', 
'0315P', '7824A']}

def time_converter(times):
    """Converts format of violation_time from HHMMP and HHMMA to datetime, assigns NaN"""
    try:
        for element in times:
            if element[-1] == 'A':
                hour = int(element[0:2])
                minutes = int(element[2:4])  
                result = datetime.time(hour, minutes)
            elif element[-1] =='P':
                hour = int(element[0:2]) + 12
                minutes = int(element[2:4]) 
                result = datetime.time(hour, minutes)
            else:
                result = 'NaN' 
        return result
    except ValueError:
        'NaN'


df['time'] = df.violation_time.apply(time_converter)
```

I expect to have a new series with garbage values eliminated and times formatted as such:
[10:37,02:31, 00:26, 15:15]
I am able to get these values outside of pandas by appending to lists, how does differ from pandas?

Comment: I would guess that the try statement is failing. If try fails and except is triggered then your function doesn't return anything, which is why you're getting None. If you add a return statement after except that could help. You could put ```return('NaN')``` instead of just 'Nan'

Comment: This is a very good illustration of why you shouldn't just put a blanket try/except block in your code. If you run it without, the `ValueError` returned leads you toward your answer

Comment: Your function iterates on row when you **apply** it. no need to loop. your **element** here is actually one character of the date, not the whole date.

Comment: Learned a big lesson today, I use pythontutor.com to analyze small pieces of my code sometimes. The program doesn't support pandas so I used lists. When returning the function to the script I overlooked the for loop. Got some insight on those return statements also. I had to add an IndexError with ValueError and its running smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it correct result as following:

```
  violation_time      time
0          +.98P      None
1          1037A  10:37:00
2          0231P  14:31:00
3          1206A  12:06:00
4          0315P  15:15:00
5          7824A      None
```

I applied `lambda` as `df.violation_time.apply(lambda x: time_converter(x))`.
And, You do not need `for loop` in `time_converter` function.

Please see the full code as following:

```
import datetime as datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'violation_time': ['+.98P','1037A', '0231P', '1206A', '0315P', '7824A']})

def time_converter(times):
    """Converts format of violation_time from HHMMP and HHMMA to datetime, assigns NaN"""
    try:
        element = times
        if element[-1] == 'A':
            hour = int(element[0:2])
            minutes = int(element[2:4])  
            result = datetime.time(hour, minutes)
        elif element[-1] =='P':
            hour = int(element[0:2]) + 12
            minutes = int(element[2:4]) 
            result = datetime.time(hour, minutes)
        else:
            result = 'NaN' 
        return result
    except ValueError:
        'NaN'


df['time'] = df.violation_time.apply(lambda x: time_converter(x))  
print (df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({violation_time: ['+.98P','1037A', '0231P', '1206A', 
'0315P', '7824A']})

def time_converter(time):
    """Converts format of violation_time from HHMMP and HHMMA to datetime, assigns NaN"""
    try:
        if time[-1] == 'A':
            hour = int(time[0:2])
            minutes = int(time[2:4])  
            result = datetime.time(hour, minutes)
        elif time[-1] =='P':
            hour = int(time[0:2]) + 12
            minutes = int(time[2:4]) 
            result = datetime.time(hour, minutes)
        else:
            result = 'NaN' 
        return result
  except ValueError:
       'NaN'


df['time'] = df.violation_time.apply(time_converter)
```